# Optimizing SQL query, altering ORs

Tags: sql, sql-server

With below condition query executes very long time. I think it depends from **or** conditions. How I can alternate these **or**s?

```
WHERE (p.tran_number = LTRIM(RTRIM(@tran_number)) OR ISNULL(LTRIM(RTRIM(@tran_number)), '') = '')
    AND (CAST(p.fiscal_date AS DATE) >= CAST(@begin_date AS DATE) OR @begin_date IS NULL)
    AND (CAST(p.fiscal_date AS DATE) <= CAST(@end_date AS DATE) OR @end_date IS NULL)
    AND CAST(@end_date AS DATE)
    AND (p.operation_type = @operation_type OR @operation_type = '-1')
    AND (
           ce.username = @username
        OR @role_code LIKE '%admin%'
        OR @role_code LIKE '%Statists_GO%'
        OR (
            (ce.username IN (
                SELECT e.domain_username
                FROM @childTable c
                LEFT JOIN FstP.dbo.employees e ON e.id = c.obj_id
                    AND c.obj_type = 'employee'
            )
        )
        AND @role_code LIKE '%supervisor%')
    )
    AND (p.rnm = @rnm OR ISNULL(@rnm, '') = '')
    AND (ce.username = @author OR ISNULL(@author, '') = '')
    AND (
           d2.docs_num = @policy_number
        OR dGate.DealNumber = @policy_number
        OR ISNULL(@policy_number, '') = ''
    )
ORDER BY insert_date DESC, fiscal_date DESC
```

Comment: Please provide execution plan...

Comment: Prepare all your variables before the query. I mean all those `ltrim`, `isnull(, '')`, `cast as date`.

Answer (score 1):

```
SET @begin_date = CAST(@begin_date AS DATE)
SET @end_date = DATEADD(DAY, 1, CAST(@end_date AS DATE))
SET @tran_number = LTRIM(RTRIM(@tran_number))

...
WHERE (p.tran_number = @tran_number OR ISNULL(@tran_number, '') = '')
    AND (p.fiscal_date >= @begin_date OR @begin_date IS NULL)
    AND (p.fiscal_date < @end_date OR @end_date IS NULL)
    AND (p.operation_type = @operation_type OR @operation_type = '-1')
    AND (
           ce.username = @username
        OR @role_code LIKE '%admin%'
        OR @role_code LIKE '%Statists_GO%'
        OR (
            ce.username IN (
                    SELECT e.domain_username
                    FROM @childTable c
                    JOIN FstP.dbo.employees e ON e.id = c.obj_id
                        AND c.obj_type = 'employee'
                )
            AND @role_code LIKE '%supervisor%'
        )
    )
    AND (p.rnm = @rnm OR ISNULL(@rnm, '') = '')
    AND (ce.username = @author OR ISNULL(@author, '') = '')
    AND (
           d2.docs_num = @policy_number
        OR dGate.DealNumber = @policy_number
        OR ISNULL(@policy_number, '') = ''
    )
ORDER BY insert_date DESC, fiscal_date DESC
OPTION(RECOMPILE)
```